# SSH config does not add key to ssh-agent automatically

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm using a MacBook Pro M1 Pro with Ventura 13.2.

I need to re-add my SSH keys to the ssh-agent after every reboot. On my old MBP it'd be done for me automatically through the config file in `~/.ssh/config`.

I generated a new key to `~/.ssh/github` (without passphrase) and added this to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *.github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
```

Then `ssh-add ~/.ssh/github`.

This should add the private key to the agent on boot automatically, but after a reboot running `ssh-add -l` returns `The agent has no identities.`. I need to add the key to the agent again manually before I can perform git operations which gets very annoying.

Comment: No, `AddKeysToAgent` just means that the first time you connect to a matching host, the key will be loaded from the file *and* added to your agent. If you want the key loaded automatically, you need to add the `ssh-add` command to, say, `.zprofile` or another relevant shell configuration file.

Comment: The major desktop environments implement their own ssh agents with access to their own keyrings, where unlocking a keyring unlocks alllll the keys, and there's a "login" keyring or some such. The only problem is, they're not compatible with each other. The GNOME and KDE keyrings can be exported to plaintext if you're willing to tolerate your secrets being temporarily exposed like that. I could wish they'd export to the base ssh with selectable passwords for each private key.

Comment: You probably want [keychain](https://www.funtoo.org/Keychain).

Comment: I have also been facing a similar issue after the update to the Ventura. I had to add ```ssh-add --apple-load-keychain``` to my .zshrc file since I am using zsh. This command will load identities form the keychain provided identities are present in the Keychain.